# Google Analytics Page Title is Showing up as H1 Tag

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, html-heading, page-title

I have been given the task of trying to figure out why **Google Analytics** page titles are showing up as the H1 for every other Page Title.

It is only happening inside of

> Behavior / SiteContent / All Pages

in **Google Analytics**, but when you go to the site it has the correct page title.

I thought it might be a cache problem but it just happened again on a new post.

I am using Wordpress, Yoast plugin, and PHP. Has this ever happen to anyone else?

Comment: Do you mean that you expect to see the text for the page title, but instead you just see "<H1>" where the text should be?

Comment: Hello Hemaolle,
Thanks for replying yes, expect to see the text for the page title, but instead you just see "<H1>" where the text should be. What's weird is it's only happening inside of the GA.